# How does one transfer JSON to/from an iOS app, securely?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services

Is there a standard protocol that is commonly followed? Or is this an area that varies greatly? How do most good iOS apps already do this in a way that prevents unintended uses or hacking?

Comment: What do you mean, _securely_? Are you aiming to ensure integrity of transferred data? Or the confidentiality of the transferred data? Or that the data is being transferred by an authorized principal? Would TLS work? If not, why not?

Comment: SSL is generally used, one way or the other.  One can also encrypt/decrypt individual files, but that's usually more complicated.

Comment: It's a total beginner question. Essentially I'm asking, how do I stop any random person from sending a unauthorized post request-for example-to my webservice? How do I secure this so only my app can send certain methods to my webservice? Hopefully this is what you were asking. Sorry I'm very new to programming, and not all that knowledgeable (obviously :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent someone from using your web service you must have some sort of password scheme, or the party on the other end must have "credentials" (ie, a fancy password) that you recognize.

Comment: Is there any names given to standard and proven ways of doing this?

Comment: Usually cursewords.  You first need to establish an SSL connection.  For that the server needs credentials from a "certificate authority" (and the appropriate software).  Then you can implement a simple password scheme, or you can use "digital signing" (and more credentials) to verify that the user is who he says he is.

Comment: (Frankly, this is almost certainly well beyond the capabilities of someone who is "very new to programming".  I've been doing this 40 years and I can barely comprehend it.)

Comment: Well by very new I mean roughly 9 months. So not a raw beginner, but very inexperienced, thanks for the answer, I'll have a look into it, but unsurprisingly I'll probably start off with a very basic implementation and update as needed. It's only a personal project anyway :) Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use a high level API (NSURLConnection API) connecting to a SSL driven web server for which you ensure the secure urls that return JSON require authentication and authorization.